# how to monitor a website's health using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, health-monitoring

I have a quick question to ask.
Suppose I have a website (the website itself is not necessarily hosted by AWS). If I want to check the health of the website for say, every 5 minutes, by making a simple get request to the root of the website.
How do I achieve this by using AWS services? What services should I use? How should the work flow look like?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Your website is where on AWS? An EC2 instance, ECS container, S3 bucket, EB platform? Do you use load balancer, route53? What is your architecture?

Comment: My load balancer is on AWS, but the DNS alias record is not provided by R53 (this part is not controlled by me). Say, I have given name such as www.example.com which points to my load balancer. I want to make a ping/get request to the www.example.com every 5 minutes to make sure it is not crashing for whatever reason.  (If the DNS record is deleted by other people, or messed up I want to be notified too). If the get request failed, it would be nice to get an email notification.

Comment: If you are not using R53, you would have to create custom solution for  it, as I don't know any build in AWS service for that. For example, use CloudWatch scheduled events to trigger lambda function every 5 minutes. lambda will request your url and if the request fails it will notifiy you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes good sense to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

One way would be to use [CloudWatch scheduled events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) to trigger lambda function every 5 minutes. Lambda will request your url and if the request fails it will notify you.

For the notifications you could setup [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) with email subscriptions.